# How to call variable that has set in new dataframe using aggregate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to use orders and quantity that I have made in new dataframe called `df2`:

```py
df2 = df.groupby('prod_name').agg(
    orders=('no_klien', 'nunique'),
    quantity=('prod_name', 'count'),
).sort_values(by='orders', ascending=False).head(10)
```

I want to use that variable for train and testing the model here ;

```py
user_items = sparse.csr_matrix((train['orders'].astype(float),(train['userId'], train['quantity'])))
item_users = sparse.csr_matrix((train['orders'].astype(float),(train['quantity'], train['userId'])))
```

The error is like this

```
KeyError: 'quantity'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 'quantity'
```

Comment: Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5211833).

Answer (score 0):

We need to have a sample of your initial "df" to help you more.

However, naively seeing a "KeyError" points to the "quantity" key not existing in your "train" structure...

Because on a dummy dataframe, your first piece of code seems to behave properly (no syntax error)...

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Please read [answer] on what the "answer" box should be used for.